# Decimal type in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

How do you define a decimal(10,2) in Loopback? I've looked around the api and examples and I cannot get it to work. It just keeps creating a decimal(10,0). columnName does affect the output but precision and scale are not set. I've also tried "precision" instead of "dataPrecision"; still no luck.

```
"Amount": {
  "type": "Number",
  "required": true,
  "dataPrecision": 8,
  "dataScale": 2
  "mysql": {
    "columnName": "Amount",
    "dataType": "DECIMAL",
    "dataPrecision": 8,
    "dataScale": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Which connector are you using?

Comment: My bad, MySQL connector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For model that use mysql connector, this should create column with `decimal(10,2)` type

```
"amount": {
  "type": "number",
  "dataType": "decimal",
  "precision": 10,
  "scale": 2
}
```

Comment: This works well up to precision of 15 but if I want a mysql decimal(20,8) it will store correctly in the database but when retrieved will lose precision as it is assigned to a Javascript Number which is a 64 bit float. Is there any way to have Loopback store it in mysql as a decimal(20,8) but retrieve it as a Javascript decimal type like Big (big.js) or as a string?